# Using tee to get realtime print statements from python

Tags: python, stdout, tee

I have a python script that looks something like this:

```
for item in collection:
    print "what up"
    #do complicated stuff that takes a long time.
```

In bash, I run this script by doing the following:

```
$ python my.py | tee my_file.txt
```

However, all I see in bash is a blank line until the program finishes. Then, all of the print statements come all at one.

Is this the expected operation of tee? Can I use tee to see the output in real-time?

Comment: This is going to be an issue with python. It's deliberate. It's simply detecting that the output isn't going to a terminal, so it's buffering. You need to turn the buffering off. How to do that is probably better suited for stackexchange.com

Comment: May be this helps: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: at the top do "`import sys`" and on an indented line below the print statement do "`sys.stdout.flush()`"

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering

Comment: The flag `-u` is here to "force  stdin,  stdout  and stderr to be totally unbuffered." and would solve your problem.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Python, like many programs, tries to minimize the number of times it calls the `write` system call. It does this by collecting the output of several `print` statements before it actually writes them to its standard output file. This process is called buffering the output.

When Python is connected to a terminal, it doesn't buffer its output. This makes sense, because the human at the terminal wants to see the output right away.

When Python is writing to a file (or a pipe), it does buffer its output. This also makes sense, because no one will see the output until the process is complete

You can defeat this optimization by calling `sys.stdout.flush()` whenever you want to force Python to write its buffered output to its standard output file.

In your case, try this:

```
import sys
...
for item in collection:
    print "what up"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    #do complicated stuff that takes a long time.
```

Comment: Great explanation! I would add that calling the script with the flag `-u` would also solve your problem, e.g. `python -u my.py | tee my_file.txt`